# Forgot pokemon trainer club player ID

Tags: pokemon-go

I know my password but I forgot my player ID of my Pokemon GO trainer club. How can I get it back?

Comment: If you can't even remember your user name, we can't help you.

Comment: I am upvoting, and encourage the downvoters to reverse their opinion, because, as demonstrated by the answer below, this IS an answerable question (and a perfectly useful one).

Comment: @DJPirtu The question is about the "Player ID" which is a number, and is different from the username.

Answer (score 5):

Use this link:

https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/forgot-username

When the page loads, you want to request desktop site in your tools menu. This will give you the same browser as you would have on laptop/desktop computer. Then enter your email address you used to sign up in "Trainer mode" and enter your birthday. Don't need to input anything else. In the email that will be sent, just click the green box "recover username".